# Low-noise audio-frequency BJT?

Tags: audio, transistors, noise, bjt

I found myself looking for a low-noise PNP transistor the other day.

I couldn't find any parametric searches that listed noise performance. Even from the transistor manufacturers. You can search by beta, \$V_{ceo}\$, and \$I_{c}MAX\$.  All these searches seem to return a table of every general-purpose part in the manufacturer's portfolio. Not helpful.

This circuit needs to have low-noise at audio frequencies.  RF transistors seems to be better characterized for noise, but they aren't necessarily low-noise at audio frequencies.

The best I have found was [a forum thread at DIYaudio](http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/solid-state/17285-ultra-low-noise-transistors.html), but the recommendations tended to be old-school, even obsolete parts. I'm looking for a mass produced transistor in SOT-23 or smaller.

So recommendations are welcome, but I'd really like to see a selection tool or parametric search that includes this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [BC859/BC860](http://www.nxp.com/products/bipolar_transistors/general_purpose_bipolar_transistors/low_noise_transistors/pnp/series/BC859_BC860.html) with a search on the NXP web site. They seem similar to the BC108 which used to be the low-noise device most people used to use.

Answer (score 1):

MPS4355 if RS (source resistance) is low — up to a few hundred ohms

2N4250 is RS a few K ohms

http://www.thatcorp.com/THAT_IC_Selection_Guide.shtml#XsistorArrays

Comment: Could you explain what 'RS' means please. Your links seems irrelevant as it doesn't contain any of the products mentioned.

Comment: @TrygveLaugstøl Source resistance driving the base of the transistor.  If it's very high, current noise dominates and you need to use an FET instead of a BJT

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but the question is still relevant -- cheap, low noise, mass produced PNP SOT-23 transistors.

The Toshiba [2SA1312](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?type=datasheet&lang=en&pid=2SA1312) is in SOT-23 with published noise specs, although I'm not impressed by NF charts. Digikey supplies them (in quantity).

The Fairchild [FJX992](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FJ/FJX992.html) looks to be a similar part with no noise specs. Mouser has singles stock at $0.294

The BC859 looks a little old in comparison, but is in current supply at Mouser.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the ham radio guys use for their  direct  conversion receivers . since the sensitivity of the direct conversion  receiver depends on the low noise  audio amplifiers that follow the RF  mixer that conversts the signal direct to audio  .   you may find some good recipes  there   cheers  mike ZL1BTB

Answer (score 0):

For audio purposes I often use the IF3602. Its over $40 each and has a huge lead time, but is the lowest voltage noise FET I've ever seen: < 1 nV/rHz at audio frequencies and has a large input impedance.

A good BJT PNP is the SSM2210. With a few of these in parallel you can get an input referred noise of ~0.5 nV/sqrt(Hz) from 0.1-10000 Hz.

Comment: SSM2210 is obsolete

Comment: True! Shows my age...

Comment: but the SSM2212/2220 seems to be a good replacement for NPN/PNP. Balanced pairs and still comes in 8-pin DIP.