# I am looking for recommendations how to lower the noise in this preamplifier circuit

Tags: low-noise-amplifier

I have a circuit using MMBT3904T-7-F parts, operating at 100uA collector current, which is rather noisy.  This is a preamp for the 475kHz ham band.

I need to stick with bipolar NPN.

How can I lower the noise in this circuit?

[image: Spice sim circuit]

Comment: Have you tried looking at manufacturers websites? They might have a more usefull search. I know when it comes to opamps, suppliers can be useless, but LT and Analog have great search options. Perhaps it's the same with discretes?

Comment: Noise can be as much a property of the **circuit** you're using as it can be a property of the transistor. Even the best transistor (regarding noise) cannot solve a noisy biasing current for example.

Comment: I haven't found much help on manufacturers sites either.  "Low noise" in transistors seems to be a lot like "really bright" in LEDs.  Everything is "low noise"....

Comment: In spice, with perfect noiseless supplies, I am seeing about 60nV/sqrt hz at this frequency.   The circuit is a simple common emitter amp, biased to have the collector at 1.4V (half the supply voltage) and 100uA collector current which is called out as the low noise operating point in AofE.

Comment: There are some helpful answers on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10406/low-noise-audio-frequency-bjt (The closing of this question caused me to pretty much give up on this site.)

Comment: What's your source impedance? I'd guess at 475 kHz, you should be able to transform your antenna Z to the transistor's optimum noise point. And at 475 kHz, preamp noise is likely a non-issue unless your antenna is really inefficient. Good low-noise transistors for low source Z are not specified as "low-noise". Odd - these tend to be bigger power transistors. Spice noise outputs are optimistic (because the transistor models usually default to Rb=10 ohms)

Comment: 2k ohms. This stage is noisy even with no input connected.

Comment: 2SC3324 will give you 1dB NF for 100µA and Zin=2k. Pretty good. If base current is a problem, you could use low noise JFET like BF862. You could also use opamp like ADA4898 (not cheap, but very very good).

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to: howto reduce preamp noise. 60nV/rt(Hz) seems excessive. Post your circuit, including 2K source Z. BTW: you should test for noise with 2K @ input, not open.

Comment: Of course it's noisy with an open circuit input! What's its noise with a short circuit on the input?

Comment: You could try cutting R13 and R1 in half to bump up the collector current in case your noise is mostly shot noise from that low of a current.  Also, a tried and true technique, if your source impedance is low enough, is to boost the voltage with a transformer before your amplifier.  Also try a higher beta transistor such as mpsA18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rethink the operating point:

[image]

I'd be inclined to run at 0.5mA or 1mA, judging from the right hand plot.
The left-hand plot gives us no guidance, because your carrier/info/modulation will be 475KHz.

Your test circuit (grounded emitter) has no ability to reject power supply noise. Stick 1Kohm in that VDD line, and drop in 1,000uF cap. Your F3dB of 0.16Hz promises 60dB atten at 160Hz, 58dB at 120hz, and 52dB at 60Hz. Now you can trust what you see on the scope as being random noise.

Consider an adaptive-bias, so temperature changes and VDD changes are less of a problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw7i2R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with LTspice noise analysis (I use a different tool). So was curious how their GUI works, and ran most of your circuit. Your circuit is not bad at all, but bear in mind that **transistor SPICE models** are generally not meant to characterize noise sources properly (they're optimistic). But you do get a picture of resistor noise source contributions.
At the collector of Q1, total noise is 186nV/rt(Hz)
Most of *that* noise is due to (R3)2K input source resistor 162 nV/rt(Hz). You'd like to have *all* the noise contributed by this resistor that's modelling your antenna's impedance.
The next worst noise contributor is R26 (14K base bias) at 62 nV/rt(Hz)
The next worst noise contributor is Q1 (2N3904) at 52 nV/rt(Hz)
The next worst noise contributor is R5 (38.3K base bias) at 37 nV/rt(Hz)
The next worst noise contributor is R13 (12K collector R) at 7.6 nV/rt(Hz)

So you can improve noise by changing your bias method. Noise contribution of bias R is helped by using a value much larger than Rs (2k). The extreme solution uses a single bias resistor from the DC supply-to-base. This will be about 2.5 Mohm. Now the transistor is the next worst noise contributor after Rs and improving noise beyond this point will involve searching for a lower-noise transistor. Bias stability is poor by doing this....but what's more important? Noise or DC operating point?
Gain is down at 475 kHz. You can improve gain by adding some inductance to Q1's collector, peaking gain at your desired frequency. Increasing this preamp gain helps by making noise contributions at Q1's collector (and beyond) less significant. You might consider reducing C27 from 1uF to perhaps 0.02uF to reduce gain at low frequencies.
At these low-RF frequencies, atmospheric noise is huge, and any halfway decent antenna will introduce background noise that dominates all these noise sources. Here's the acid test...Terminate your preamp with your antenna's characteristic impedance (you suggest its 2k ohm). Monitor output noise. Then replace the termination with your antenna. Does the noise increase? If so, doing better involves a huge effort.

Comment: Ok, thanks Glen!   The higher collector current definitely improves things in the real circuit.  Spice disagrees, and tells me that lower collector current = lower noise.  :(    I thought about adding a tank in the collector leg, but even with shielded inductors, I worry it will radiate.  They never say anything about shielding effectiveness in the specs.

Comment: The 2N3904 might not be the best transistor here, but I am not finding transistors that have pertinent data in this frequency range.  Is there an online resource for selecting RF transistors in this frequency range?

Comment: @user103218 Can't recommend a selection resource. 2N3904 is a decent choice. *Any* BJT (at these frequencies) is potentially unstable when matched to Rsource & Rload. Tuned collector can be squirrely if too-high Z. F(t) depends greatly on Ic. JFET  J111, J310 might yield low noise (biased to large Id). JFETs would want to see a high-Z source with common-source amp.